# New constructors for classes with Scala rich wrapping (implicit)

Tags: scala, constructor, implicit-conversion

In Scala, you can "add new methods" to existing classes by creating wrapper class and using "implicit def" to convert from the original class to the rich wrapper class.

I have a java library for graphics that uses plenty of constructors with looong lists of floats. I would love to add new constructors to these classes with rich wrapping but this doens't seem to work like the above for methods. In other words, I would like to have simpler constructors but still to be able to keep using the original class names and not some wrapper class names but currently I see no other options.

Ideas?

Comment: Don't you just want a factory?

Comment: That is probably the best solution, to create a separate object factory.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use Scala's apply(...) factory methods, which you build in to the companion object for your class.

For example, if you have:

```
class Foo(val bar: Int, val baz: Int) {
  ... class definition ...
}
```

You could add (in the same file):

```
object Foo {
  def apply(bar: Int) = new Foo(bar, 0)
}
```

With this in hand, creating a new Foo instance, just providing the bar parameter, is as easy as

```
val myBar = 42
val myFoo = Foo(myBar) // Note the lack of the 'new' keyword.
```

This will result in myFoo being assigned an instance of Foo where bar = 42, and baz = 0.

Comment: Yes. @Janne, in short, you're right, you simply can't “emulate” a new constructor that you'd call with `new`, but you can use this technique instead.

Comment: The library is a third party library so I don't want to modify the classes there and I think for the same reason I can't create companion objects for those classes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a combination of the "[Pimp my Library](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766)" approach and an [apply factory method](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/factory-methods-and-companion-objects.html).