# scala parameterized type with constraint appearing after the colon?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, parameterized-types

I was looking at the source for Sorting.scala, and was curious about 
the definition of the last method in the source snippet below.

```
object Sorting {
  /** Quickly sort an array of Doubles. */
  def quickSort(a: Array[Double]) { sort1(a, 0, a.length) }

  /** Quickly sort an array of items with an implicit Ordering. */
  def quickSort[K: Ordering](a: Array[K]) { sort1(a, 0, a.length) } //<<??
```

The type parameter 'K'  seems to be constrained to be a subtype (perhaps?) of
'Ordering'...  But I have never seen this syntax.

I would sort of (no pun intended) understand if 
the method were defined something like:

```
  def quickSort[K <% Ordering[K]](a: Array[K]) { sort1(a, 0, a.length) }
```

But I am puzzled by the meaning of a constraint that has just the colon.  Any links to relevant documentation or further (explained) examples would be awesome.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Check out [What are Scala context and view bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465948/what-are-scala-context-and-view-bounds). View bounds are deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a 'Context Bound'. 
Found the  answer in  a very good book I'm now reading 'Programming Scala'.  From Chap 5. on Implicit arguments... here is an example that
explains what is going on:

```
case class MyList[A](list: List[A]) {
  def sortBy1[B](f: A => B)(implicit ord: Ordering[B]): List[A] =
    list.sortBy(f)(ord)

  def sortBy2[B : Ordering](f: A => B): List[A] =
    list.sortBy(f)(implicitly[Ordering[B]])
}

val list = MyList(List(1,3,5,2,4))
list sortBy1 (i => -i)
list sortBy2 (i => -i)
```

The type parameter B : Ordering is called a context bound. It implies the second, implicit argument list that takes an Ordering[B] instance.

More [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3XqrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT222&lpg=PT222&dq=This%20idiom%20is%20so%20common%20that%20Scala%20provides%20a%20shorthand%20syntax,%20which%20is%20used%20by%20the%20second%20implementation&source=bl&ots=uoZEZAbonH&sig=HMchBCqqS4QVpqRopB38FnNWyVc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI5JeUmOnNxwIVATuICh3NKw6x#v=onepage&q=This%20idiom%20is%20so%20common%20that%20Scala%20provides%20a%20shorthand%20syntax%2C%20which%20is%20used%20by%20the%20second%20implementation&f=false)

Comment: Context bounds are very often used (as in this case) with [_type classes_](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) -- in fact, I'd say, type classes are the reason they have been introduced.